# WordPress не видит jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу решить проблему сам!

Пытаюсь натянуть вёрстку на WordPress. В вёрстке есть slickslider и там он работает отлично. Когда пытаюсь подключить к WordPress, то там он не работает!
Стили и скрипты подключил, вроде правильно, ниже будет functions.php файл.

В header.php такой код (т.е. wp_head прописал и стили самой темы подключились)

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick-theme.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Candara" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
```

В footer.php прописал wp_footer

```
     </footer>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>  
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

Файл functions.php

```
 <?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_theme' );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'scripts_theme');

function style_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/css/main.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('slick_theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/css/slick-theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/css/slick.css' );
}

function scripts_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/jquery-3.3.1.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/main.js' ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/jquery-3.3.1.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('slick.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/slick.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/slick.js' );
}
```

Сам main.js файл с настройкой слайдера

```
    jQuery('.sl').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed:1500,
    dots:true,
    /*Убрать стрелки навигации*/
    // arrows:false,
});
```

Из решений я перепробовал уже:
1) менять $ на jQuery, менял только в одном файле, в том, который писал сам. В скачанных js файлах это не делал, потому что код там очень объёмный.
2) проверял синтаксис
3) пробовал отключить jQuery wordpressa, и подключить свой. Подключать как с сайта, так и с компьютера

Проблема, думаю в том,что WordPress не читает jQuery, но почему не знаю((((
Если сталкивались с таким , то напишите как решили. Буду очень благодарен)

Ошибки 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правки:
Файл functions

```
    function scripts_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' )  ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('slick.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/slick.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/slick.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

js файл

```
    jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ){    
    $('.sl').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed:1500,
    dots:true,
});
```

Также я удалил скрипты и стили в header и footer
и подключил jQuery из Wordpress, такой строкой

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Ошибки в консоли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. `assetc` пишется как `assets` 2. Зачем jquery 2 раза подключаете? 3. Приложите хотя бы ошибки в консоли

Comment: Я исправил и подключил jQuery 1 раз, не заметил моё упущение(не работает)
Ошибки приложил

Comment: У вас сайт в папке wordpress домена localhost находится? или вы для примера так сделали. Посмотрите на ошибки, у вас не доступно ничего, вы явно с путями недомудрили. Попробуйте для сайта создать отдельный домен локальный

Comment: Я создал новую тему в htdocs=>wordpress=>wp-content=>themes=>(название моего проекта) в котором лежат все файлы.

Answer (score 1):

У вас четыре ошибки.

1. Не заданы зависимости в подключении скриптов

```js
wp_enqueue_script('slick.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/slick.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Остальное - по аналогии. подробнее на русском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script).

2. Нет обёртки в js-файле. WP по умолчанию подключает jQuery в режиме совместимости, так что $ не работает. Поэтому jQuery скрипты оборачивают в WP
   следующим образом:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // ... ваш скрипт
});
```

3. Не надо подключать jQuery 3.3, не отключив стандартный jQuery в составе WP. Вы только создаёте этим лишние проблемы. slickslider прекрасно работает и со стандартным jQuery 1.12.4.
4. Не надо подключать скрипты и стили дважды - в header/footer и через `wp_enqueue_`.

**Update**

Согласно последним правкам, ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
function scripts_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/main.js', array( 'jquery', 'slick' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assetc/js/slick.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я внёс все ваши правки в код, но слайдер до сих пор не работает! Возможно из-за того что я новичок то допустил глупую ошибку в синтаксисе кода. Я прикрепил исправленный код выше, посмотрите пожалуйста, думаю там могут быть ошибки. Буду премного благодарен за помощь!
P.S. также я прикрепил скрин с ошибками из инспектора, возможно он покажет что-то.
Исправленный код идёт после слова (Правки:)

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` -лишняя строка, WP всегда сам подключает jQuery. Впрочем, она не создаст ошибку.

Comment: Так у вас файл main хочет использовать slick, а slick ещё не запущен. Укажите правильно зависимости для main: `array( 'jquery', 'slick.min', 'slick' )`

Comment: И кстати, зачем slick.min и slick? По-моему, это один и тот же файл, только минифицированный. Укажите один

Comment: А нужно прописывать array( '  ' ) для стилей?

Comment: wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css', array('  ') );

Comment: Я могу отправить Вам файлы, что бы вы сами посмотрели. Уверен ошибка простая, но из-за того что я мало знаю, её не вижу(

Comment: Я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Для стилей надо прописывать зависимости, если они зависят друг от друга

Comment: Да, код в functions выглядит именно так, но скрипты всё равно не подключаются

Comment: Что в консоли сейчас, какие ошибки?

Comment: Я прикрепил скрин ошибок

Comment: Ну что вы в самом деле. Вам предельно четко все браузер написал в консоли - не может найти slick.js - путь указан неверный. И синтаксическая ошибка в main.js - оборван текст скрипта. Скобки за вас я считать должен? Добавьте в конец main.js `});`